# Best way to store whether data exists in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

If we ask the following question of an individual: "Does that person have children?" There are three possible answers: "Yes", "No", "Unknown". With a table design that stores the person as a record in a `people` table, and a child as a record in a `children` table with a foreign key to the `people` table, we cannot distinguish between "No" and "Unknown". Both answers imply no rows in the `children` table.

What is the best way to store the answer to that question that can distinguish between the three states? My current thought is storing that information as a separate field on the `people` table, but that opens up data integrity issues.

Comment: Just have a `has_unknown_children` flag within the `people` table. A person can have unknown children whether or not he/she also has any known children (represented by rows in the `children` table), so there are no integrity issues.